# Can the focused element be centralized in ScrollTo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

I'm using the [ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) method in JQuery. Can I centralize the element horizontally which has focuesd?

Any help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use $(window).height() for the window height and $(document).scrollTop() (space between document start and current scroll height) for calculating the middle position of the screen.

```
var middleHeight = $(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2.0;
```

Comment: For horizontal you can do something like this:
var middleWidth = $(document).scrollLeft() + $(window).width() / 2.0;